# Fruit Leather in Gemara Sukkah

Tags: sources-mekorot, beis-hamikdash, grapes-wine, masechet-sukkah, story-identification

It's been a while since I learned Sukkah....

Does anyone know where the Gemara talks about where the wine from נסכים goes; through an אמה (canal) to a container, where it sat and congealed until it had the consistency of [Fruit Leather](http://www.stretchislandfruit.com/); this container cleaned out every 7 *x* (7? 70?) years.

---

*So you want the story? ....someone asked me what happened to the wine from the נסכים, and remembered this גמרא but not where it is....*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Sukka* (49[a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=7&daf=49&format=text)-[b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=7&daf=49b&format=text)) describes this and mentions that the young Kohanim would clear out the congealed wine from the *shitin* (a large cavern beneath the altar, into which the libations would run, see Rashi 49a s.v. שיתין) every 70 years. In a *b'raisa*, Rabbi El'azar bar Tzadok describes the "congealed wine" as "similar in form to cakes of pressed figs":

> אמר רבה בר בר חנה א"ר יוחנן שיתין מששת ימי בראשית נבראו שנאמר חמוקי ירכיך כמו חלאים מעשה ידי אמן חמוקי ירכיך אלו השיתין כמו חלאים שמחוללין ויורדין עד התהום מעשה ידי אמן זו מעשה ידי אומנותו של הקב"ה תנא דבי ר' ישמעאל בראשית אל תיקרי בראשית אלא ברא שית תניא ר' יוסי אומר שיתין מחוללין ויורדין עד תהום שנאמר אשירה נא לידידי שירת דודי לכרמו כרם היה לידידי בקרן בן שמן ויעזקהו ויסקלהו ויטעהו שורק ויבן מגדל בתוכו וגם יקב חצב בו ויטעהו שורק זה בית המקדש ויבן מגדל בתוכו זה מזבח וגם יקב חצב בו אלו השיתין תניא א"ר אלעזר בר צדוק לול קטן היה בין כבש למזבח במערבו של כבש ואחת לשבעים שנה פרחי כהונה יורדין לשם ומלקטין משם **יין קרוש שדומה לעיגולי דבילה** ובאין ושורפין אותו בקדושה שנא' בקדש הסך נסך שכר לה' כשם שניסוכו בקדושה כך שריפתו בקדושה מאי משמע אמר רבינא אתיא קדש קדש כתיב הכא בקדש הסך נסך וכתיב התם ושרפת את הנותר באש לא יאכל כי קדש הוא כמאן אזלא הא (דתניא) נסכים בתחילה מועלין בהן ירדו לשיתין אין מועלין בהן לימא רבי אלעזר בר צדוק היא דאי רבנן הא נחתו להו לתהום אפילו תימא רבנן בדאיקלט ואיכא דאמרי לימא רבנן היא ולא ר' אלעזר בר צדוק דאי רבי אלעזר אכתי בקדושתייהו קיימי אפילו תימא רבי אלעזר אין לך דבר שנעשה מצותו ומועלין בו אמר ריש לקיש בזמן שמנסכין יין על גבי מזבח פוקקין את השיתין לקיים מה שנאמר בקדש הסך נסך שכר לה' מאי משמע אמר רב פפא שכר לשון שתיה לשון שביעה לשון שכרות אמר רב פפא שמע מינה כי שבע איניש חמרא מגרוניה שבע אמר רבא צורבא מרבנן דלא נפישא ליה חמרא ליגמע גמועי רבא אכסא דברכתא אגמע גמועי

Summary from [Kollel Iyun HaDaf](http://dafyomi.co.il/sukah/points/su-ps-049.htm):

> 1) THE PRIMORDIAL OPENINGS BENEATH THE MIZBE'ACH
>
> (a) (Rabah bar bar Chanah citing R. Yochanan): These openings [Shitin]
>   originate in the six days of Creation (proof text which is further
>   expounded to teach that the openings go down to the depths, Hash-m's
>   Handiwork).
>
> (b) This is supported by Tana d'vei R. Yishmael from the word
>   Bereishis, and by R. Yosi in the Beraisa (expounding the Pasuk in
>   Yeshayah 5).
>
> 2) BURNING THE USED WINE
>
> (a) (R. Elazar b. Tzadok): There was an opening (Lul) on the western
>   side of the Mizbe'ach, between the Kevesh and the Mizbe'ach into which
>   the wine dripped (not going to the depths).
>
> (b) **Once in 70 years the young Kohanim would bring up the coagulated
>   wine which was burnt** (Isur Hana'ah), as learned from ba'Kodesh Hasech
>   Nesech Shechar LaShem.
>
> 49b----------------------------------------49b
>
> (c) Question: How does this Pasuk imply that the wine remaining in the
>   Shitin must be burnt?
>
> (d) Answer (Ravina): The work Kodesh links the Nisuch to the Sereifah.
>
> (e) Question: Who, then, is the author of the teaching that Nesachim
>   only have Me'ilah prior to Nisuch but not after?
>
> 1. Answer: It is R. Elazar b. Tzadok (since, according to Rabanan, the wine went down to the depths and was not around to be burned!).
> 2. Answer: It could even be Rabanan, speaking where it happened that the wine was caught in a Kli before it could descend.
> 3. Alternate Question: It seems that this teaching is Rabanan since, according to R. Elazar b. Tzadok it must be burned while this Mishnah
>      teaches that there is no Me'ilah after its use!?
> 4. Answer: It could even be R. Elazar, since nothing could have Me'ilah after its Mitzvah has been done (and the burning is not m'Ikar
>      ha'Mitzvah).
>
> 3) FILLING UP FROM WINE
>
> (a) (Resh Lakish): The Shitin were plugged up during the Nisuch so
>   that the "throat" of the Mizbe'ach should appear full (as the Pasuk
>   ba'Kodesh Hasech implies).
>
> (b) Question: How is this learned from ba'Kodesh Hasech?
>
> (c) Answer (R. Papa): The word Shechar implies fullness.
>
> (d) (R. Papa): The satisfaction from wine comes from the throat (not
>   the stomach).
>
> (e) (Rava): A Talmid Chacham who does not have much wine should drink
>   the little that he has in large gulps, to derive satisfaction
>   therefrom (Rava would thus enhance his experience from a Kos Shel
>   Berachah).

Comment: We tied!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: The timestamp is the same. Must have been less than a second difference.

Comment: Both answers are great, but I think I'll accept this one [A] because when I asked SE to sort the answers by "Oldest," this one came up on top ;) [B] you summarized the גמרא......thank you and @DoubleAA very much! :)

Answer (score 3):

You're probably looking for the bottom of [49a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=7&daf=49&format=pdf).